# Use Nested LDAP-Groups in Tomcat WebApp as auth-Constraint

Tags: java, tomcat, ldap

i have a Tomcat WebApp with JNDI Realm authentication. Everything works fine. Now i want a Group as auth-contraint in the web.xml which has a Sub-Group with the Users of the Web App. The users are memberof Group1 and Group1 is memberof Group2.  How can i obtain to use Group2 as the auth constraint?

user --> Group1 --> Group2

```
<auth-constraint>
            <role-name>DN=Group2<role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

The user is getting a 403 Forbidden.   When is use group1 where the user is directly member it works fine.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Greetingz